# .Net Hot reload is not working properly in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli, hot-reload

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and using the hot reload feature in visual studio 2022. When any changed made in the API project (like changing the routes) is getting reflected on the swagger screen immediately and its not working in the below cases.

1. Any changed made in the reference projects. Application is showing a warning to rebuild the application to get the new changes.
2. Any changes made in the startup.cs is not getting effected. Page is getting refreshed after saving the file but the changes are not getting reflected.

I have tried the above mentioned scenarios.